# Can I see the reason for a flag?

Tags: support, flags

I made a quite detailed question to the best of my ability, and still I got a close vote. Of course it does not mean anything, since it was just one flag, but still I was curious to why it was flagged.

I don't care who flagged me, but is it *generally* possible to see the reasoning behind a flag/close vote? When I flag a post I need to tick one of several boxes, with an optional reason, so it should be viewable somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I concur. IIRC the system already notifies you on the first vote for some of the close reasons (duplicate, possibly "unclear what you're asking"). I always wondered why the other close reasons remain hidden from the questioner until their post is closed for good.

Comment: What question would that be?

Comment: @RobertLongson, while it remains a general question, the specific question mentioned was this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41792624/applying-state-changes-that-apply-to-many-elements-in-a-block/41793490#41793490

I am not asking for any flag to be removed, and while of course it would be nice to see the reason for this sole question, I would like to know if there is a general way of seeing such reasons.

Comment: @oligofren well since I can cast a close vote on your question I can see the previous vote cast. In this instance: primarily opinion based. I don't think that there is a way if it's your Q though... Short of an automated comment being put on your Q

Comment: Can you not click on the close link and see what option was picked?

Comment: ah, ok, well that makes sense in the form that any naming scheme, such as BEM, is primarily guiding principles, which by definition has no definitive answer.

Comment: @NathanOliver - Does that link show up for flags as well as close votes? Because if it shows up for flags too then 1) I don't have to keep posting flag reasons as comments and 2) I'm going to be a lot angrier at the next "require a comment for down votes" feature request that pops up.

Comment: @NathanOliver, don't know how I missed that! Yes, I can see the blue flag of 1 on the "opinion based" option. Not using my close privileges enough, apparently... That is at least half the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @Patrice Well, if it's your own question you only need 250 rep to cast a close vote on it, not the normal 3k, so the OP will have an easier time getting to the point of being able to see those close votes.

Comment: @BSMP No, it doesn't show up for flags, only actual close votes.

Comment: @BSMP It should only show up for close votes and not flags.  A close flag only puts the post in the close vote queue.  It does not actually contribute to the close votes on the post.

Comment: @Servy thanks for the correction. I was under the impression short of the "community" dupe'closing an OP couldn't close his own posts. My bad

Comment: If a question is flagged, dumped into a review queue, and literally *none* of the users with voting privileges agreed with the flag and cast a vote of their own (which you could see, as previously discussed), then the flag is just noise and you shouldn't care about it at all.

Comment: A duplicate close flag shows the linked question in the close dialog